# NoSql database for effeciently scanning multiple composite rowkeys

Tags: performance, hbase, graph-databases, nosql

We have been using Hbase for quite sometime. Problem we are facing with it is the scan + filter performance. We took a well-known approach with key-value, columnar store which is to create composite rowkey representing most of your query filters. e.g. `customerid|calmonth|transactionid|productid|itemid` . User is allowed to query multiple calendar month, transactions, products and items at a time. Since data in hbase is naturally sorted our approach has been either of following:

1. Scan based on startrow and endrow which include `customerid|startmonth` and end `customerid|endmonth`. Get all the data in server and apply rest of the filters in app server
2. Scan based on startrow and endrow which include `customerid|startmonth` and end `customerid|endmonth`. Also apply ColumnValueFilter since we also store some filter values as a CQs.

Both of above approach is not scaling now. SCAN is our only use case . It's read only table. I know I can try hbase a RowFilter with RegEx comparator but I was wondering if there's another NoSQL option that address this naturally. i.e. having a tree-like structure for a rowkey and importantly can traverse multiple branch in parallel so it doesn't suffer in performance. I'm looking at graph database like neo4j but I am not sure at this point if that's a right choice.

Comment: How many rows do you have per customer_id|month ? If you have a lot, getting these to your app server from hbase is bottleneck, i think.

Comment: It really is. It's 10s to 100s of thousands depending upon query. I can certainly identify different workload and do different processing and/or storage for those

Answer (score 0):

Since you have several access paths, you will need indexes to make that performant and a rudimentary cardinality mechanism to pick which index to use.  You could slap Splice Machine on top of it and have it working pretty quickly.  It is open source...